# bash: bundle: command not found

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to follow [this](https://github.com/cyli/logstash-output-slack) installation but get the following error:

```
bash: bundle: command not found
```

I can't seem to find what bundle is? What is it and how do I install it.

Answer (score 1):

To install it run `gem install bundler` and check [this](http://bundler.io/#getting-started) for more configurations